# Getting error undefined controlled sequence when trying to make a function of module

Tags: luatex, lua

In the following code, the function named `json_parser` is meant to parse the JSON. I had initially kept this function as a separate module named `json.lua` and required it using:

```
local json = require("json")
```

but for some reason, I wanted to pack this in one file and tried to create a function out of it. It worked fine but after making it a function, I am getting an error. I am using this code inside a latex file and running it using `lualatex`.

```
    \begin{luacode}
    local function json_parser()
        local lpeg = assert(require("lpeg"))
        local C, Cf, Cg, Ct, P, R, S, V =
            lpeg.C, lpeg.Cf, lpeg.Cg, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.P, lpeg.R, lpeg.S, lpeg.V

        -- number parsing
        local digit    = R"09"
        local dot      = P"."
        local eE       = S"eE"
        local sign     = S"+-"^-1
        local mantissa = digit^1 * dot * digit^0 + dot * digit^1 + digit^1
        local exponent = (eE * sign * digit^1)^-1
        local real     = sign * mantissa * exponent / tonumber

        -- optional whitespace
        local ws = S" \t\n\r"^0

        -- match a literal string surrounded by whitespace
        local lit = function(str)
            return ws * P(str) * ws
        end

        -- match a literal string and synthesize an attribute
        local attr = function(str,attr)
            return ws * P(str) / function() return attr end * ws
        end

        -- JSON grammar
        local json = P{
            "object",

            value =
                V"null_value" +
                V"bool_value" +
                V"string_value" +
                V"real_value" +
                V"array" +
                V"object",

            null_value =
                attr("null", nil),

            bool_value =
                attr("true", true) + attr("false", false),

            string_value =
                ws * P'"' * C((P'\\"' + 1 - P'"')^0) * P'"' * ws,

            real_value =
                ws * real * ws,

            array =
                lit"[" * Ct((V"value" * lit","^-1)^0) * lit"]",

            member_pair =
                Cg(V"string_value" * lit":" * V"value") * lit","^-1,

            object =
                lit"{" * Cf(Ct"" * V"member_pair"^0, rawset) * lit"}"
        }

        return { parse = function(str) return assert(json:match(str)) end }
    end

    local socket = require("socket")

    local json = json_parser()
    local file = io.open("sample-true.json")
    local start = socket.gettime()
    tab = json.parse(file:read("*all"))
    texio.write_nl("Time passed parsing JSON: " .. socket.gettime() - start .. " s\string\n")
    file:close()
\end{luacode}
```

The part in the yellow is the error, that I get. What could be the reason for it?
[image]

Comment: Always try to make *complete* examples so that other people don't have to build the test document themselves (and guess what you have in the preamble).

Comment: If you are using non-trivial amounts of Lua, it is _much_ better to put it into a separate file and `require()` that from `\directlua`. The differences in handling of characters by Lua and TeX make intermixing beyond short fragments _painful_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The luacode-environment still executes tex-commands and so the \t explodes. Use the luacode* environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

% gives error:
\begin{luacode}
 -- \t
\end{luacode}

% works:
\begin{luacode*}
 -- \t 
\end{luacode*}


\begin{document}

bkbkbk
\end{document}
```

Comment: It gives an error saying `invalid escape sequence near '\s'` Is there any other change I could need to make?

Comment: \string should be imho \\string. Or perhaps remove that line ...

Comment: Okay! Could you tell the difference between `\begin{luacode}` and `\begin{luacode*}`? Will be helpful, if you could update in the original answer.